# Updating App in Mac App Store with a higher OS requirement

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-lion, mac-app-store

Currently my app requires snow leopard and above.. Can I send an update to the Mac App Store that requires Lion and above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer from Apple.
Yes, I can submit an update with a higher OS requirement.
Drawback: users with previous OS will not be able to download any version.